# Slicing neo4j Cypher results in chunks

Tags: sorting, neo4j, cypher, slice

I want to slice Cypher results in chunks of 100 rows, and be able to retrieve a specific chunk.

At the moment, the only way to ensure that rows are not mixed-up is to user ORDER BY which makes the query very inefficient ( 3sec. for me is too much)

```
MATCH (p:Person) RETURN p.id ORDER BY p.id SKIP {chunk}*100 LIMIT 100
```

where {chunk} is an external parameter to identify a specific chunk.

Any suggestions?

PS: the property p.id is indexed.

Comment: Why do you need chunks? Can't you retrieve larger batches, like 100k at a time?

Comment: You can also keep the cursor open and read 100 at a time from the cursor

Comment: You can use external engine for index. `Elasticsearch`, for example.

Comment: Thanks all. We are building a Web API to give external access to some data and I wanted to give paginate results. My approach was minimalistic: passing the REST parameter "page" (api.startp-network.org/v1/people?page=5) directly to the query. probably was too minimalistic

Comment: Michael thanks, sure I can retrive all nodes. But takes to much time for a web API query.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like adding label to Person before extracting chunks and then using query like

```
Match (p:Chunk:Person) with p LIMIT 100 
Match (p) remove p:Chunk
Return *
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the `p.id` values are unique and dense** (say, the value starts at 1 and increments, without any gaps), then this query will take advantage of the index on `:Person(id)` to efficiently get each hundred-Person chunk:

```
WITH (({chunk} - 1) * 100 + 1) AS startId
MATCH (p:Person)
WHERE p.id IN RANGE(startId, startId + 99) 
RETURN p.id 
ORDER BY p.id
```

Now, practically speaking, your `id` space will probably not remain dense, even if it started out that way. `Person` nodes will be deleted over time. In that case, the above query can return fewer than 100 rows. So, you can make your chunk size bigger than 100 and do some post-processing to get the 100 you need. In the worst case, you may need to make multiple requests to get the 100 you need, but each request will be fast. (Ideally, you would want to assign no-longer-unused `id` values to new `Person` nodes, to fill up gaps in the `id` space -- but this would require you to scan for the gaps.)